# Images alignment on subfigure

Tags: subfloats

My senses of perfectionism tints and I cannot assert the images alignment on the link below. Could you help me?

https://www.overleaf.com/7127148195djnmzfkjtczd

Best regards,
Bruno

Comment: Please provide in question a small document, which reproduce your problem. Link can be death after while ... so the most people are not keen to use them (include me).

Comment: simply remove the `\newline`

Comment: Well, thanks. :)

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto in case the answer was helpful please upvote and/or accept the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% ========== Packages ==========
\usepackage{graphicx, geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[english]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\title{Teste 123}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Trajectories time development from Fig. \ref{fig:circ_line_traj}}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{}
        \includegraphics[trim = 1cm 0cm 1cm 0cm, clip, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:dstates_tracking_e}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{}
        \includegraphics[trim = 1cm 0cm 1cm 0cm, clip, width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \label{fig:dstates_tracking_e}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: done sir as suggested